# How to download marketcaps data from yahoo finance in R?

Tags: r, download, yahoo-finance

I want to download marketcaps values for a set of stocks. I have a code that downloads historical prices of the stocks but it would be great to also have market caps (not necessary history) even the last one would be great. Can someone help me out on this one?

Below is what I use to download the prices

```
prices <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(YH[,1])){
    prices <- try(get.hist.quote(as.character(YH[i,1]),
                                 start=date,
                                 quote='Open'
                                 )
                  ,silent=TRUE
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwgwE.png)

Comment: Hello Nelli, this isn't really a programming or code question. They key to answer this question is, how to get a data source with the relevant information. This could mean simply downloading a new data set, scraping web data or using a package that provides the API to get the data. In any case base r will not have a function out of the box to download market caps. Please add a bit more information on what kind of solution you are looking for here? Do you have a problem getting a specific package to work, joining data sets, etc?

Comment: Welcome to stack: Your question as it is will be hard to answer/ you don't give data, nor internet link; Could you specify what you want to get, indicating teh link to the data you want to scrap ? And see [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I just want to know if it is in principle possible to download the marketcaps data from yahoo finance as one csv file. With prices it works, but I don't know how to do it for marketcaps

Comment: @Fnguyen thank you for your responses. In a nutshell, I have a list of tickers (stocks) and I want to download their MarketCap. To be honest I don't really care which tool to use. Now I am doing it manually, but there are 80 companies so it would be nice to have a solution to download all of them together. I thought I can do it in R from Yahoo FInance. But there it is notin historical data, but on Summary tab for each stock. If you know any solution for it please let me know.

Comment: So you are looking for a package that contains an API to download data like this. I'd recommend looking in CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/.